Is my use case really a Dual Write problem ? Or am I over complicating my solution
I have an application that needs to write a file to S3 and then put the path to newly written S3 object on a Kafka message. This functionality is called during a REST API request.
In my understanding if I have a solution like below its a classic case of dual write as if after writing to S3 if my write to Kafka fails that S3 file won't be processed downstream.
func processEvent(event Event) {
    String s3Path = writeToS3(event);
    writeToKafka(messageWithS3Path);
}

So to avoid this I'm utilising S3 notifications and only write to S3 as part of REST call. Once its written in S3, an object creation notification is triggered via SQS which I consume and then write to Kafka.
Now my question is am I complicating my solution ? Can't I just retry entire processingEvent logic if write to Kafka fails or in general anything fails ? Something like below
func retryHelper(Event event) {
  boolean isDone = false;
  do{
    try{
      processEvent(event);
      isDone = true;
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      log.error("Write to at least one system failed.. retrying..")
    }
  } while(!isDone)
}


func processEvent(Event event) {
    String s3Path = writeToS3(event);
    writeToKafka(messageWithS3Path);
}

Will that be a valid solution to avoid my dual writes if I don't care If I have some S3 files orphaned (where Kafka write failed) ?
I know that with this solution there could be infinite retries but if we are only considering transient errors (or cap the retries to a large number say 50-100) will this be a valid (albeit hacky) solution ?

The dual-write problem is quite common scenario and there are different opinions on solving this problem.
Most common approach is to solve this is using Outbox pattern where first the data should be written to S3 first and then a seperate process will receive event from S3 and publish it to Kafka topic/SQS. Using this approach you can make the call asynchronously, decouple it to Event-driven approach and use the retry logic in the SQS or Kafka.
Whereas if it is all implicit in code like this, it might go in infinite loop in worse conditions.
func retryHelper(Event event) {
  boolean isDone = false;
  do{
    try{
      processEvent(event);
      isDone = true;
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      log.error("Write to at least one system failed.. retrying..")
    }
  } while(!isDone)
}

func processEvent(Event event) {
    String s3Path = writeToS3(event);
    writeToKafka(messageWithS3Path);
}

I typically use the S3:PutObject or other S3 events trigger notifications and publish it to SQS as well to be processed by Kafka or other services to be processed. It is quite common practice.

Correct and that is how I'm also solving it. But my question is more around complexity of solving the dual-write, is there no middle ground ? On one end there is a possibility of infinite retries and on the other a bunch of more technologies and service for outbox pattern.

I haven't come across with any middle ground yet except decoupling the architecture by adding an event layer and bunch of addition technologies. :(

An alternate approach is to put the burden on the caller: fail the request if the message is not written to Apache Kafka. Then the Apache Kafka topic is the source of truth (so single write) and the AWS S3 is just a data store.
Clients would have to know to retry when the publish failed. You also pay the cost of rewriting the same data multiple times to AWS S3, but then your system is less complicated. The trade is yours to decide.
